# What's the point of using save() in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm learning MongoDB and Mongoose, and I've watched instructors advise to use the save() function to save the changes made to the database.

But I'm still making changes successfully without using save().
I've made two functions to add a document to the database, one with using save() and the second one without using save(), and they all did the same job.

So, what's the point of using it then?

NOTE: I've hided my connect string

My Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//-- Connect to Database --//:
mongoose.connect();

// make Schema & model:
const Person = mongoose.model('Person', new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number
}));

//-- Interact with Database --//:
async function run1 () {
    const person = await Person.create({name: 'John', age: 25});
    await person.save();
    console.log(person);
}

async function run2 () {
    const person = await Person.create({name: 'Sally', age: 40});
    console.log(person);
}

run1();
run2();
```

Terminal output:

```
PS C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Folders\Programming\Web Development\Web Development Projects\Database-Practice> node server
{
  name: 'Sally',
  age: 40,
  _id: new ObjectId("61d20d852b1e59a6b21149b1"),  __v: 0
}
{
  name: 'John',
  age: 25,
  _id: new ObjectId("61d20d852b1e59a6b21149b0"),  __v: 0
}
```

Picture of my Database after running my code:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## From the docs:

> Shortcut for saving one or more documents to the database. `MyModel.create(docs)` does `new MyModel(doc).save()` for every doc in docs.

### Looking at what you've got, let me point out:

```js
async function run1 () {
    const person = await Person.create({name: 'John', age: 25});
    await person.save(); // unnecessary 2nd call here
    console.log(person);
}
```

### Behind the scenes your code will run like:

```js
async function run1 () {
    const person = await new Person({name: 'John', age: 25}).save();
    await person.save(); // saving twice basically
    console.log(person);
}
```

### What you can do is (this is preferred by most):

```js
async function run1 () {
    const person = new Person({name: 'John', age: 25});
    await person.save();
}
```

The reason is that doing so gives you **more control** when saving your document. For example, you can pass the person object to any function and save it inside that function instead without requiring the model to wherever that function exists in your codebase.

```js
async function run1 () {
    const person = new Person({name: 'John', age: 25});
    await doSth(person); // showing possibility, not a recommendation
}

// This function can exist anywhere, does not have to be in the same file
async doSth(person){
  // do some logging maybe
  // change some properties of the person maybe
  // slug-ify the persons name maybe
  await person.save();
}
```

Doing this allows you to have a better **separation of concern**. Other than that, both will produce the **same behavior** and is pretty much **a matter of preference**. But the current standard in the community goes with the `.save()` method.